# Composing subclasses to achieve type restriction

Tags: scala, subclass, type-resolution

I am new to Scala and learning to code a personal project in it.

I have this issue and looking around did not help much. So here it is -

```
abstract class Service{
 def containsFeatures(x: Feature*) = ??? 
 } 

object Service1 extends Service{..
 def containsFeature(x: Feature*)
 }

object Service2 extends Service{..
 def containsFeature(x: Feature*)
 }

Trait Feature

case object A extends Feature
case object B extends Feature
case object C extends Feature
case object D extends Feature
case object E extends Feature
case object F extends Feature
case object G extends Feature
```

I would like to restrict my code in such a way that Service1 defines which features are possible and which are erroneous. 
Eg: 
    Service1 allows composing objects A, C, E, G and shows error when other features are supplied.

Is this possible to programmatically restrict this just with our definition of Service1 without modifying the other classes?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to make something like this? 
Service1.containsFeature(List(A,C,E,G)) // OK

Service1.containsFeature(List(B,D,F)) // throws Error

Comment: You mean it should show an error at compile time, right?

Comment: Yes, an error at compile time.

Comment: @WonpyoPark Yes, that was what I wanted to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want scalac to show an error at compile time when a wrong `Feature` is supplied, AND you cannot alter anything other than `Service1` then it is not possible. The compiler accepts or rejects a call to `Service1.containsFeature` based on its interface, but its interface is already defined in `Service` where it says that it will accept *any* `Feature`.

If you CAN change things about the other code, there are some ways to do this. For instance if you can change everything:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class Service[Allowed <: Feature] {
  def containsFeatures(x: Allowed*): Unit
} 

object Service1 extends Service[S1Feature] {
  def containsFeatures(x: S1Feature*): Unit = println("ok")
}

object Service2 extends Service[S2Feature] {
  def containsFeatures(x: S2Feature*): Unit = println("ok")
}

sealed trait Feature
sealed trait S1Feature extends Feature
sealed trait S2Feature extends Feature

case object A extends S1Feature
case object B extends S2Feature
case object C extends S1Feature
case object D extends S2Feature
case object E extends S1Feature
case object F extends S2Feature
case object G extends S1Feature

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> Service1.containsFeatures(A,B,C)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : B.type
 required: S1Feature
       Service1.containsFeatures(A,B,C)
                                   ^

scala> Service1.containsFeatures(A,C,G)
ok
```

Comment: If I were to change the signatures, Defining a subclass of Feature to define these compositions and updating the method signature to the appropriate subclass is the way to go about it?

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's interesting to see this pattern of usage. However, this now places a compiler check when I try to pass an object of type Service1 to a method that takes in Service type. I guess this is the trade-off in this approach?

Comment: @Adarsh Yes in methods where a `Service` is expected you will now have to pass around the `Allowed` type parameter.